# How to inform R that the first column of my dataset is row names? And how should change the class of data frame to vector or matrice?

Tags: r, correlation, stat

```
   APD<- read.csv("APD.csv",header=FALSE)
  rar<- read.csv("rar.csv",header=FALSE)
 ## Making column name labels
 tree<-rep("tree",100)
 tree_labels<-c(1:100)

colnames(APD)<-c(paste(tree,tree_labels, sep="")) 
 colnames(rar)<-c(paste(tree,tree_labels, sep=""))

  correlation.csv<- cor(x=APD, y=rar, method = "spearman")
```

The above script suppose two calculated correlation between columns of two data sets . But there are two problem it starts labeling the output from the first column (which is the row name) so the last score gets NA as label. I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly or not but maybe for the same reason R thinks APD is a data frame so does not calculate the last line.

Cheers

subset of csv file

```
   V1              V2                V3    V4
t1  9.368703877 9.693286792 12.44129352 13.06908296
t10 8.128921254 8.940227268 11.40226603 12.17704779
t11 7.87062995  8.697508965 11.39250803 12.17704779
```

After read it in it's like below

```
    V2           V3            V4            V5
    V1          V2               V3         V4
 t1 9.368703877 9.693286792 12.44129352 13.06908296
t1  08.128921254    8.940227268 11.40226603 12.17704779
t11 7.87062995  8.697508965 11.39250803 12.17704779
```

Comment: Turns out when reads in the data , adds another row as column names!!

Comment: It just looks like your second table does have column names. When using `header=FALSE` you're telling R that there are no column names. Just use `header=TRUE` when reading the second table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem, you can use `row.names`:

```
APD <- read.csv("APD.csv", header = FALSE, row.names = 1)
rar <- read.csv("rar.csv", header = FALSE, row.names = 1)
```

From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html):

> `row.names`: a vector of row names. This can be a vector giving the actual row names, **or a single number giving the column of the table which contains the row names**, or character string giving the name of the table column containing the row names.

For the second problem, you can use `mapply`:

```
mapply(cor, APD, rar, MoreArgs = list(method = "spearman"))
```

assuming that you want the correlation between the 1st column of each table, then the 2nd column, and so on.

---

Using your example:

```
> str(a)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ V1: num  9.37 8.13 7.87
 $ V2: num  9.69 8.94 8.7
 $ V3: num  12.4 11.4 11.4
 $ V4: num  13.1 12.2 12.2
> mapply(cor, a, -a, MoreArgs = list(method = "spearman"))
V1 V2 V3 V4 
-1 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: Error in (function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson",  : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: at this point, I'm afraid I can't help if you don't give us some sample data

Comment: @Jack you gave one table, not two. And with that example, it works just fine. Use `str(APD)` and `str(rar)` to see the structure of your tables.

Comment: but you are not going through that labeling thing, right? thats the cause I guess

Comment: @Jack see the comment above. You don't have to use `header=FALSE`